# How to give information from a button?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have four buttons like:

[image]

I also have a gameobject that attaches my script to it

Under the script I have one function, that should print the text of the button, when I use it in onClick() buttons.

Inspector

[image]

How to call one function on different buttons and print out the text of those buttons, that the user clicked?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of passing the `string` to the callback function, it would make more sense to pass the `Button` instance itself. If you do this, you will be able to access more data from the `Button` if needed in the future.

```
public Button[] Btn;

void OnEnable()
{
    //Register Button Events
    for (int i = 0; i < Btn.Length; i++)
    {
        int btIndex = i;
        Btn[i].onClick.AddListener(() => buttonCallBack(Btn[btIndex]));
    }
}

private void buttonCallBack(Button buttonPressed)
{
    Debug.Log(buttonPressed.GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text);

    if (buttonPressed == Btn[0])
    {
        //Your code for button 1
    }

    if (buttonPressed == Btn[1])
    {
        //Your code for button 2
    }

    if (buttonPressed == Btn[2])
    {
        //Your code for button 3
    }

    if (buttonPressed == Btn[3])
    {
        //Your code for button 4
    }
}

void OnDisable()
{
    //Un-Register Button Events
    for (int i = 0; i < Btn.Length; i++)
    {
        Btn[i].onClick.RemoveAllListeners();
    }
}
```

If you still want to pass the Button text **only**:

```
public Button[] Btn;

void OnEnable()
{
    //Register Button Events
    for (int i = 0; i < Btn.Length; i++)
    {
        int btIndex = i;
        string btText = Btn[btIndex].GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text;
        Btn[i].onClick.AddListener(() => buttonCallBack(btText));
    }
}

private void buttonCallBack(string buttonText)
{
    Debug.Log(buttonText);
}

void OnDisable()
{
    //Un-Register Button Events
    for (int i = 0; i < Btn.Length; i++)
    {
        Btn[i].onClick.RemoveAllListeners();
    }
}
```

Remember to assign your `Buttons` to the `Btn` variable slot in the Editor or you will get the `null` exception error.

Comment: Thanks but i have about 300 buttons i think its not a good way of that.

Comment: If you have 300 buttons and only need the `Text` from them, use the second solution in my answer. The code will always be the-same and the events are automatically registered and un-registered. By the way, why do you think it is not a good way of doing that?

Comment: Sorry i didnt see the second solution that works for me Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Don't forget to accept answer if your problem is solved. Happy coding!

Comment: Yeah sure Thanks :)

Comment: @NewHacker 3 Weeks later.... [Here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) is how to accept answers.

Answer (score 1):

Rather taking all the buttons in the list. Make a script Button.cs and give it to each UI buttons

In that script make one public method

```
public void OnButtonClickListener(int index) {
    // Do your code here for button click using its index
}
```

now you just have to assign callbacks of each UI buttons to this public method and pass the argument of button's index.

I hope this will help you...